Flutter project blows up when adding Auth0
I'm trying to create a Flutter project with Auth0 login. Here is what I did:

Created a new Flutter project. "flutter create my_project".
Switched to my_project, ran "flutter doctor", and saw that there were no issues.
Ran "flutter pub get" followed by "flutter run". Since an Android device was connected to my computer, it built the default Android app, and ran it on my phone.

So far, so good. I went to this page for further instructions:
https://auth0.com/docs/quickstart/native/flutter/interactive
The Auth0 project already exists. I added Auth0 to my Flutter project:
"flutter pub add auth0_flutter"
Then I updated my app/build.gradle file with the "manifestPlaceholders" property, as described.
Now I try to run my app again:
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run
The first error message says:
e: Incompatible classes were found in dependencies. Remove them from the classpath or use '-Xskip-metadata-version-check' to suppress errors
There are about a thousand more of these. At the end of it all, it says:
Your project requires a newer version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin.Find the latest version on https://kotlinlang.org/docs/releases.html#release-details, then update
android/build.gradle:
ext.kotlin_version = ''
Doing this made no difference. I tried both 2.0 and 1.9.24.
I've actually repeated these steps three times, and in the interim tried a bunch of other things, but I cannot get past this problem. I have the latest version of Android Studio installed and the latest SDK.
I would like to report this problem to Auth0, but I can't find any way to contact them.
Thanks,
Frank

Can you build and run the example app? https://github.com/auth0-samples/auth0-flutter-samples/tree/main/sample

Thanks for the suggestion. It does not, but the error messages that appear when I try to build it are different: No file or variants found for asset: .env.
Target debug_android_application failed: Exception: Failed to bundle asset files.
